# Ordering string labels from a dictionary in a bar chart

Tags: python, bar-chart

I am writing a script which will produce a bar chart from a dictionary. I know that as a rule, the dictionary items are unordered. Is there any way of ordering them just for the bar plot?

```
cats=dict((x, events.count(x)) for x in events)
fig=plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("HEALTH records", fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_title("Number of records {0}, collected on {1} animals".format(len(events), len(anims)), fontsize=10)

ax.bar(range(len(cats)), cats.values())
plt.xticks(range(len(cats)), cats.keys())
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
ax.set_xlabel("Health codes")
ax.set_ylabel("Counts")
plt.savefig("HEALTH records {0}.png".format(pop))
plt.clf()
```

[image: current graph]

Comment: That is not SQL what you posted. How is this related to SQL?

Comment: @branwen85 . . . I removed the SQL tag.  You should add the tag of the software you are actually using.

Comment: I'm really sorry, it remained after the last question I was going to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table and insert the dictionary items into it. Then query the table, ordered by your key field, and plot those results.

Comment: Is that the only way? I was thinking about it, but thought there would be some more direct way...

Comment: Please specify which language / framework / tools you are using and maybe we can figure out another approach.